# Multi-class API + Endpoints Proto Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

When separating the API classes into multiple files, the API explorer shows the same request definition for all resources.

So based on the structure shown below (my apologies if it's too long), in the API explorer, both **my_api.api_a.test** and **my_api.api_b.test** show the same attribute, **attr_b**, which is the last in the api_server list definition. If I change it and put ApiA last, then both methods show **attr_a**.

Any idea what am I doing wrong

```
    # model/model_a.py
    class A(EndpointsModel):
      attr_a = ndb.StringProperty()

    # model/model_b.py
    class B(EndpointsModel):
      attr_b = ndb.StringProperty()

    # api/__init__.py
    my_api = endpoints.api(name='my_api', version='v1')

    # api/api_a.py
    @my_api.api_class(resource_name='api_a')
    class ApiA(remote.Service):
      @A.method(name='test', ...)
      ...

    # api/api_b.py
    @my_api.api_class(resource_name='api_b')
    class ApiB(remote.Service):
      @B.method(name='test', ...)
      ...

    # services.py
    from api import my_api
    application = endpoints.api_server([ApiA, ApiB])
```

Also tried to define the api_server as shown below, but didn't work at all.

```
    application = endpoints.api_server([my_api])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed similar issues (which might be a bug in the endpoints-proto-datastore libary) when the actual method names (not the name in the decorator) are the same in different api classes.

Doesn't work:

```
class ApiA(remote.Service):
  @A.method(...)
  def test(self, model):
    ...

class ApiB(remote.Service):
  @B.method(...)
  def test(self, model):
    ...
```

Works:

```
class ApiA(remote.Service):
  @A.method(...)
  def test_a(self, model):
    ...

class ApiB(remote.Service):
  @B.method(...)
  def test_b(self, model):
    ...
```

You skipped those lines in your sample, but the behaviour you state matches what I encountered in this scenario.

Comment: Awesome! That was it. Thanks a lot Scarygami

Comment: @scarygami Is this related to https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/issues/91?